# Company relocation allowance was taxed as income, but then forfeited & paid back. How can I get the tax back?

Tags: united-states, taxes, relocation

I recently quit a job where I was forced to pay back a portion of relocation expenses the company gave. This money was taxed as income. What will I have to do to reclaim the taxes I paid on that money? The company made me reimburse them for the full amount, before taxes.

Comment: which tax years?

Answer (score 5):

If you return the money in the same tax year - it will not appear on your W2 and you will not be taxed on it. Whatever was withheld - you'll get it refunded when you file your annual tax return.

If you return it in a different tax year - it becomes a miscellaneous deduction reported on your Schedule A. If the amount is less than $3000 - then this deduction is subject to the 2% AGI threshold, if the amount is more than that - it is not subject to threshold.

Bottom line, you're probably going to lose money, unless you're already itemizing and the amount is above $3K.

There's also a credit that you can take instead of deduction. See [publication 525](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p525/ar02.html#en_US_2013_publink1000229600) for details.